# Regex - Split message into groups

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-group

I want to split this message into groups:

```
[Rule] 'Server - update repository' [Source] 10.10.10.10 [User] _Server [Content] HTTP GET http://example.com
```

Expected result:

```
Group1: [Rule] 'Server - update repository'
Group2: [Source] 10.10.10.10
Group3: [User] _Server
Group4: [Content] HTTP GET http://example.com
```

It does not have to be 4 groups, sometimes it can be less / more.
Pattern I tried to built:

```
(\(^\[\w+\].*\)){0,}
```

Comment: You will see that those answering have made different assumptions about your desired result, as it could be interpreted as an array, hash or string. The problem is that, as written, it is not a valid Ruby object. If, for example, you wish to return an array, you should write "Expected result:" as `["[Rule] 'Server - update repository'", "[Source] 10.10.10.10", ... ]`. Similarly, you should enclose the string in double quotes. You should always express Ruby objects as valid objects. That may also facilitate cutting and pasting by those testing code when preparing answers...

Comment: ...Also, it  is helpful to assign inputs to variables. Here, for example, you might write, `str = "[Rule] 'Server - update repository'..."`. That way, users can refer to the variable `str` in answers and comments without having to reproduce the string itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
string = "[Rule] 'Server - update repository' [Source] 10.10.10.10 [User] _Server [Content] HTTP GET http://example.com"

regexp = /\[?[^\[]+/
string.scan(regexp)
#=> ["[Rule] 'Server - update repository' ", "[Source] 10.10.10.10 ", "[User] _Server ", "[Content] HTTP GET http://example.com"]
```

Or when you prefer a hash to be returned:

```
regexp = /\[(\w+)\]\s+([^\[]+)/
string.scan(regexp).to_h
#=> { "Rule" => "'Server - update repository' ", "Source" => "10.10.10.10 ", "User" => "_Server ", "Content" => "HTTP GET http://example.com" }
```

Comment: One more question - is there possibility to split it further? So for example `Rule` is key and `'Server - update repository'` is value

Comment: @h0llym0lly I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: It should be noted that in the array returned each string but the last ends with a space. If that is not desired you can change your regex to `/\[?[^\[]+(?<! )/` to prevent the matches from ending with a space.

Answer (score 3):

If there will be no <kbd>[</kbd> in the group text this might work.

```
str = "[Rule] 'Server - update repository' [Source] 10.10.10.10 [User] _Server [Content] HTTP GET http://example.com"
```

```
str.split("[").each_with_index {|c, i| puts "Group #{i}: [#{c}" if i > 0}
Group 1: [Rule] 'Server - update repository' 
Group 2: [Source] 10.10.10.10                    
Group 3: [User] _Server                          
Group 4: [Content] HTTP GET http://example.com
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea of removing the left bracket and then putting it back in.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-split).

```
str = "[Rule] 'Server - update repository' [Source] 10.10.10.10 [User] _Server [Content] HTTP GET http://example.com"
```

```
str.split(/ +(?=\[)/)
  #=> ["[Rule] 'Server - update repository'",
  #    "[Source] 10.10.10.10",
  #    "[User] _Server",
  #    "[Content] HTTP GET http://example.com"]
```

The string is split on one or more spaces followed by a left bracket. `(?=\[)` is a *positive lookahead*.

---

If you wish to create a hash with keys `:Group1`, `:Group2`, and so on, you could write

```
arr = str.split(/ +(?=\[)/)
```

```
arr.each_index.with_object({}) do |i,h|
  h.update("Group#{i+1}".to_sym => arr[i])
end
  #=> {:Group1=>"[Rule] 'Server - update repository'",
  #    :Group2=>"[Source] 10.10.10.10",
  #    :Group3=>"[User] _Server",
  #    :Group4=>"[Content] HTTP GET http://example.com"}
```

---

Depending on requirements here is another option.

```
RGX = /\[([A-Z][a-z]+)\] +([^\[\]]+[^ \[\]])/
```

```
str.gsub(RGX).with_object({}) { |_,h| h[$1] = $2 }
  #=> {"Rule"=>"'Server - update repository'",
  #    "Source"=>"10.10.10.10",
  #    "User"=>"_Server",
  #    "Content"=>"HTTP GET http://example.com"}
```

This uses the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes a single argument and has no block, returning an enumerator. This form is useful but odd, as it has nothing to do with string replacement.

We can write the regular expression in *free spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
/
\[          # match '['
(           # begin capture group 1
  [A-Z]     # match an uppercase letter
  [a-z]+    # match one or more lowercase letters
)           # end capture group 1
\]\ +       # match ']' followed by one or more spaces
(           # begin capture group 2
  [^\[\]]+  # match one or more chars other than '[' and ']'
  [^ \[\]]  # match one char other than ' ', '[' and ']'
)           # end capture group 2
/x          # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```